# Site Permission from template to new site

Tags: permissions

I want to have a site template with the following features:

- SharePoint User Groups created for user access
- Libraries are added and permissions are set at each library
- Libraries may have different permission settings, such as

  - Internal Documents are TEAM only
  - One Page is PUBLIC ("Site" description)
  - A forum is TEAM + EXPERTS

When I use this template to create a site, the SP groups are getting applied to new site but not for the individual libraries (they use the site permissions).

How to configure the site template to keep the fine grained permissions?

Answer (score 1):

Item security can not be copied as part of a template. If your requirement is for new sites of a particular template to have unique permissions set, you will need to achieve this result using custom code.

To do this you could create a simple event receiver on the Web provisioning event. It would check the template type and apply permissions. However you need visual studio to do this.

An alternative could be to use client side code (javascript) to do this as well.